# Running MX Player on a Nexus 10 to access an ext4 USB Flash drive

Tags: usb-on-the-go, samsung-nexus-10, mx-player

How would I play an MP4 on a USB Flash drive connected to the Nexus 10?  The drive was formatted with Ubuntu with `ext4` format.  I have the MX Player but it does not see the USB Flash drive.

Comment: First question: Assuming you are using an OTG cable, is your phone able to detect the USB drive using a file manager?

Comment: Yes, I have an OTG cable. I haven't seen a file manager on this Nexus 10.

Comment: Try installing File Expert or something similar. Let me know if your phone can see it.

Comment: I've installed `File Expert HD`.  I'm not familiar with this application but I don't seem to be able to find the USB Flash device attached via OTG cable.

Comment: See my latest answer. Try using a different OTG cable. Or try the app I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Android can use only FAT32 because of permissions in ext file systems. If you have a [terminal emulator](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=terminal%20emulator) installed + root + [busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox) you can do it like that:

1. Open terminal;
2. Type `su` to get root;
3. Insert cable and flash drive;
4. Type `dmesg` to get device name;
5. Make a folder using your file manager;
6. Try to: `mount -t ext4 /dev/(device name) (path to folder you make)`;
7. Enter the folder: `cd (path to folder)`;
8. Change the file permissons: `chmod 777 (your file)`;
9. Go to that folder with file manager and play.

Or you could just use [StickMount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.stickmount&hl=uk).